# Display uploaded files using arrays in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to make a PHP site that uploads files (videos in this case) and displays them. I'm trying to store them in an array and then display them on the page. The problem is, the page is only displaying the last video uploaded, i.e. the array is only storing the last uploaded file. How can I make it so that the array stores the first uploaded file in `$array[0]`, the second in `$array[1]`, and so on... And then display them?

Here's my code (HTML form)

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Video to Upload: <br> <input type="file" name="video" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></p></form>
```

PHP code (`upload.php`)

```
<?php
$videoname = $_FILES["video"]["name"];


$tmp_name = $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"];

$thevideos = array();

if (isset($videoname))
{
    if (!empty($videoname)) 
    {
        $location = 'uploaded/';

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$videoname);


        $thevideos[] = $videoname; // the array is only storing $videoname in $the videos[0]??


        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($thevideos); $i++)
        {
            echo "<video width=\"320\" height=\"240\" controls>
           <source src=\"/uploaded/" .$thevideos[$i]. "\">
           </video> <br>";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please choose a file.";
    }

 }

?>
```

Comment: Please note that you're allowing anyone to upload PHP/ASP/CGI/and other script files, and hence can upload a shell and destroy your server - see all your files - see all your source code - your DB credentials - etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I'm fully aware, I will put up restrictions once the program is functional the way it's supposed to.

Comment: So, the user uploads only one video at a time? And you want to show all previous uploads? `$thevideos` will be an empty array each time, you need a way to get the previously uploaded videos.

Comment: Yeah, the user uploads one video at a time. So the videos are stored in the /uploaded/ directory, is there a way to go through the directory and display the videos?

Comment: Yes, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php to get started.

Comment: Thanks! It worked with the scandir() function and I was able to display them with the array.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you'd like to get a listing of all files within a directory, you should consider using the [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) or [`glob`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) functions.

`scandir` is a good selection if you need to list all content in the directory and `glob` is a good selection if you need to list files based on wildcards or extensions.